# Extension Operator for $W^{1,\infty}(U,X)$

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, banach-spaces, sobolev-spaces, hilbert-spaces, extension

I am reading through some lectures on Sobolev spaces and the vector-valued (or Banach space valued) version of them. At this moment I am very interested in extension operators for the vector-valued Sobolev space $W^{1,\infty}(I,X)$ where $X$ is a Banach space and I is a compact interval. For $p\neq\infty$ there are many references for extension operator for $W^{1,p}(I,X)$, however for $p=\infty$ I can not find good results. My question is, is there an extension operator $E:W^{1,\infty}(I,X)\to W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R},X)$ under the general assumption that $X$ is a Banach space? What I thought was the following: it is known that $W^{1,\infty}(I,X)$ coincides with the space of Lipschitz functions. By the Kirszbraun theorem there exists a Lipschitz extension of such functions but one has to assume that $X$ is a Hilbert space and even then one is not ready because $W^{1,\infty}(\mathbb{R},X)$ is bigger than the space of Lipschitz functions on $\mathbb{R}$, isn't it? Can maybe someone assists with this question?

Answer (score 2):

Say $I:=[a,b]$. We may extend $u$ simply putting it constant for $t\ge b$ and $t\le a$, that is $Eu(t):=u((t\vee a)\wedge b)$. This defines a norm-$1$ linear extensor $E$.